Liquibase with Bigquery - creating a stored procedures results in bigquery prematurely ending the script the moment it finds an END
I'm using liquibase to make changes into a BigQuery database.
This is my procedure:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `dataset.sp` (var STRING)
BEGIN
    DECLARE objects ARRAY<STRING>;

    FOR object IN
      (SELECT * from UNNEST(objects))
    DO
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;

        --do something

        COMMIT TRANSACTION;

    END FOR;
END;

This works perfectly in BigQuery studio.
When I try to use liquibase, I get this error:

Syntax error: expected ";" but got end of script

After some testing, I concluded that liquibase thinks the script is over whenever it finds an END. Any END, it doesn't matter which, immediately ends the scripts, which of course results in an incomplete script that throws a syntax error. In my case its that END FOR.
I'm using include to run the changelog:
<include file="changelogs/changelog.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true" />

And the changelog itself is just the SQL copied above.
I tried all manner of changes to the changelog itself, but none of them work. Liquibase always terminates the instant it reads the end.
How can I fix this?
